# What is the best practice when using cypress for testing?

Tags: cypress

Question 1: Should we run tests on all branches? Or just on master branch?

Question 2: When should the cypress tests run? On each commit or there is other approach?

Comment: Not sure if it is the best practice, but our team has separate branches for APi testing, E2E cypress testing and project development and we schedule the tests to run every night after work hours so we can have the results to analyze in the morning. Practice have shown that separating branches prevents most conflicts and deploy problems, and running tests on each commit is very hard to set, makes the deploy process too long and requires 100% coverage, which is not possible in reality.

Comment: we run the tests on a test server deployed by the master branch - after manual testers have approved it. but the tests are separated in their own branch for deploying on CI.